# Parse JSON stream data in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, rest

When the HTTP response is of the type **application/x-json-stream**, Is there any module or a way in javascript to parse this content?

The response is multiple JSON without any delimiters.

```
{"key":"value"}{"key":{},{},{}}{"key":"value"}
```

There is no delimiter between the objects(not even newline).
After parsing the output should be

```
[{"key":"value"}, {"key":{},{},{}}, {"key":"value"}]
```

Comment: The idea is that each update is delimited by a line break. You need to parse the response when an update is received and process each new line individually. There are libraries which can do this for you if you search

Comment: is there any space between the closing and opening brace of the next object,  I mean `}{` ?  then maybe you can try `<string>.replaceAll('}{',  '},{')`. after that append `[` and `]` in the sides and JSON.parse the string. not so sure it will work as expected!

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman if JSON objects contain }{ character or comma your solution will break.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There is no line break or any delimiter.

Comment: @ChinnmayBS we need to put the {},{},{} inside an array then if it needs to be correctly parsed.